# How to i convert the website into mobile responsive with php

Tags: php, web

how to convert the Php Site into Mobile Responsive,
 i know that possible with js and css , but how to do the same with php is it possible and how to do

Comment: If you know you can build a responsive site using JS and CSS, you also know that the server side of things has very little to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea but this link may help you: http://mobiledetect.net/

```
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {

}
```

Anyways, that will only detect if that's a mobile device and probably which one, I believe you're misunderstanding the concepts of php.
Try to find a way to use js or css.

Comment: ya i expect this one

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use sanely use PHP for this.

To make a site responsive you need to change the layout in response to the window size.

PHP is not a presentation language. CSS is a presentation language.

PHP runs on the server. The server doesn't know what the window size of the client is unless you use JavaScript to discover it and then make an additional HTTP request to tell the server what it is. That will then fail if the window size is changed while the page is open.

You could also examine the user agent string sent to the server, use that to make assumptions about what the window size was, and serve up different stylesheets / content based on that. This is a terrible idea as user agent strings do not map cleanly onto window sizes and you'll be in a constant race to keep up with new devices.